# Create Facebook Comment on a URL without using Social Plugin, is there an API?

Tags: facebook, api, comments

is it possible to create comment on a page (an url like http://mysite.com/mypage ) without using Social Plugin ?

Using graph api I mean. I don't see this possibility in Facebook documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't post new comments to a comments plugin without using the plugin itself

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: I know I can post comments on any facebook object id but if I don't have any object id, how can I link my new url without using Social Plugins and create an object id with my new url... I don't see any informations in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: my mistake _You **can't** post_, so thank you